# Retrieving Information from Task Manager using Powershell

Tags: powershell, vbscript, taskmanager

Am currently working with a business automation software, the idea is Robots simulate user actions. Is there a way to access the task manager through powershell as the robots are meant to manipulate the task manager e.g Pass in a value to start a new task, end a process and view the performance of the cpu etc . I know this can be achieved using powershell scripts or better still vb script.  Please how do I achieve this?

For the records, I am using a windows 7 machine with powershell version 3.0.

Comment: Which kind of robots?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen More like Virtual machines. The robotic system is  called Blue Prism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `get-process` for a list of running processes.

With i.e. `get-process myprocess |stop-process` you can stop `myprocess`.

For new processes you can `&` them ( `& C:\Windows\System32\taskmgr.exe`) or use the `start-process` (check `Get-help Start-Process` for help ) cmdlet.
You can also use `Invoke-WmiMethod`for this :

`Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList taskmgr.exe'`

Answer (score 1):

**List running processes and terminate calculator.**

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")

For Each objItem in colItems
    msgbox objItem.ProcessID & " " & objItem.CommandLine
    If objItem.name = "Calculator.exe" then objItem.terminate
Next
```

**Monitor for notepad exiting and restart it.**

Also available is `Win32_ProcessStartTrace` and `Win32_ProcessStartStopTrace`

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set objEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace")

Do
    Set objReceivedEvent = objEvents.NextEvent
    msgbox objReceivedEvent.ProcessName
    If lcase(objReceivedEvent.ProcessName) = lcase("Notepad.exe") then 
        Msgbox "Process exited with exit code " & objReceivedEvent.ExitStatus
        WshShell.Run "c:\Windows\notepad.exe", 1, false
    End If
Loop
```

The WMIC command line program uses same classes as vbscript (and powershell), so you can use it for help.

```
wmic /?
wmic path win32_process /?
```

or using the only available in wmic aliases of `process` alias for `win32_process`

```
wmic process /?
wmic process call /?
wmic process get /?
```

and for other uses of wmic

```
wmic /node /?
wmic /format /?
```