# Get process ID given the description with VBScript

Tags: cmd, vbscript

What's the simplest way of getting the process ID or image name from a given description using CMD or VBScript?

For example, [image]

`Description = "My application*"`, I want to get all the process ID's having that description.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to enumerate processes is WMI. However, unfortunately the `Description` property of the [`Win32_Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372.aspx) class stores only the exectuable name, not the information the Task Manager displays in its "Description" field. That information is retrieved from the [extended attributes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176615.aspx) of the executables.

You can do the same with VBScript, but it requires additional code:

```
descr = "..."

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Function Contains(str1, str2)
    Contains = InStr(LCase(str1), LCase(str2)) > 0
End Function

'Define an empty resizable array.
ReDim procs(-1)

For Each p In wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process")
    dir = fso.GetParentFolderName(p.ExecutablePath)
    exe = fso.GetFileName(p.ExecutablePath)

    Set fldr = app.NameSpace(dir)
    Set item = fldr.ParseName(exe)

    'Determine the index of the description field.
    'IIRC the position may vary, so you need to determine the index dynamically.
    For i = 0 To 300
        If Contains(fldr.GetDetailsOf(fldr, i), "description") Then Exit For
    Next

    'Check if the description field contains the string from the variable
    'descr and append the PID to the array procs if it does.
    If Contains(fldr.GetDetailsOf(item, i), descr) Then
        ReDim Preserve procs(UBound(procs) + 1)
        procs(UBound(procs)) = p.ProcessId
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wmic process where description='notepad.exe' get processed
```

for help

```
wmic /?
wmic process get /?
```

Is the way to do it. Above is command but VBScript has access to same objects, here's a post using the objects [Retrieving Information from Task Manager using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005306/retrieving-information-from-task-manager-using-powershell).

Comment: It is CMD not powershell, although PS has access to same objects as all window's languages do.

Answer (score 0):

The tasklist-command could be a solution for you.

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq MyApplication*"
```

It has also parameter to format output in CSV, which may be useful for further processing of the results.